# Laravel: route model binding exception handling in ajax request

Tags: laravel, model, binding, routes

Laravel version 7.x

I am submitting the `create` and `edit` methods via ajax request and its working fine. But, in my application there is a module which is dependent on a parent module, such as: `Employee` and `EmployeeEmergency`. So I added the `Employee $Employee` parameter in the `create` method and the `route` to handle this request.

However, If the `Employee` identifier is correct, it works fine. But, if the identifier is invalid then it throws an exception.

```
{
    "message": "No query results for model [App\\Employee] $arrayModel->token",
    "exception": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\NotFoundHttpException",
    ...
}
```

I can handle this exception by removing the `route model binding` and the authenticate the `Employee` manually. But, that will just increase the code unnecessarily.

I want to handle this exception with a proper response, something like `Employee identifier is invalid` or something like that to notify the user and prevent error.

*Employee.php*

```php
class Employee extends Model
{
    ...

    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'token';
    }

    ...
}
```

*EmployeeEmergencyController.php*

```php
use App\Employee;
use App\EmployeeEmergency;

class EmployeeEmergencyController extends Controller
{
    public function create(Employee $employee)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

*Web.php*

```php
Route::get('employee-emergency/create/{employee}', 'EmployeeEmergencyController@create')
    ->name('admin.employee-emergency.create');
```

Is there any solution for this out of the box..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let me note that the error you receive, is way bigger than usual, because you have `APP_DEBUG` set to `true` and `APP_ENV` set to `local` in your `.env`, if `APP_DEBUG` is `false` and APP_ENV= production, the error should be reduced to a plain 404.

Second, if you look in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#explicit-binding

You can see that you can customize the behaviour like so:

```
//App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider.php
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::bind('employee', function ($id) {
        $employee = App\Employee::where('id', $id)->first();
        if (empty($employee)) {
            throw new \Exception('Employee not found');
        }
        return $employee
    });
}
```

EDIT:

- Updated laravel link
- Updated answer itself

Comment: Now i am getting this `Declaration of App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::boot(App\Providers\Router $router) should be compatible with Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::boot()`

Comment: My bad, you do not need the `Router $router` in the boot parameters anymore. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Its hitting the `employee.show` method and even that stopped loading. I need this to hit `employee-emergency/create/{employee}`. However, I tried changing the `employee` to `employeeEmergency` but no luck, its the same error every time

Comment: Just to be clear: The variable name you bind in the routeServiceProvider 'employee', is the variable name you use in the route, like `employee-emergency/create/{employee}`. Every route that has a `{employee}` in it, can use it. So the thing you are saying does not make sense. Can you post the code you have now?

Comment: Thanks @Rob. Actually I am using this Route Model Binding for the first time, so it was kind of a difficult thing for me. But, its working now. I'll put the final code shortly. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Rob, here is my final code.

*RouteServiceProvider.php*

```
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::bind('employee', function ($token) {
        return \App\Employee::where('token', $token)->first() ?? false;
    });
}
```

In the Controller

```
public function create($employee)
{
  if($employee == false)
  {
    # setting success message
    session()->flash('warning', 'Could not find the reference for the given `Employee`');

    # redirecting
    return response()->json([
      'success' => false
    ], Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
  }

  ...
}
```

However, this code is working for me. But, can it still be improved..?

Comment: Yes @Rob you are right, actually I tried that first. I need that to redirect to the `index` page with the warning message, but since the requirement of the application is to load and submit the form using ajax, it was not working as I require it to be. Therefore, I had to take this approach. If you think it can be improved depending on this scenario, then please post the better way. I really appreciate it. Thanks :)